# nodeJS request POST To localhost:3000 ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, express, post, request, econnrefused

At one point I just want to make a `POST` request to my `rails` server running on `localhost:3000`

If a use like `postman` on even `cUrl` I can ping my API

But kow, with my node app I want to do this :

```
    var req_body = {
       'my_id': id,
        'dataTable': data }


    var options = {
       method:   'POST',
       url:      config.get('api_url') + 'end_tracking',
       json:     true,
       body:     req_body
      }
      //  config.get('api_url') return http://localhost:3000/

      request(options, function (error, response, body) {
                console.log(error)
    ... }
```

this is what I get :

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:896:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:919:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1073:14)
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 3000 }
```

and as I said, if I do this request directly with postman, everything works !

Comment: Looks like running node app uses the same host and port as rails app.

Comment: my node app is on 8080

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally did it !

For a unknown reason, accessing `localhost:3000`, launched with `rails s` didn't work at all on my node server

but I worked when I started the rails server with `rails s -b 0.0.0.0` !

Comment: amazing solution to a problem i was spending hours trying to fix. thanks. one question though, this strategy caused my Mac OS to ask for permission for ruby to accept incoming network connections. is this safe? what security considerations does this option entail? and is there documentation somewhere on the `-b` option? It doesn't seem to be in the build-in rails help menu.

Answer (score 0):

how i did this , just use the same structure and i hope it works for you

```
request({
        url: url, //URL to hit
        method: 'post',
        headers: headers,
        timeout: 10000,
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }, function (error, result, body) {
        if (error) {
           console.log(error);
        } else if (result.statusCode == 500) {
            console.log('not found');
        } else {
            console.log('success')
        }
    });
```

hope it works.

Comment: same thing :(
if I try to get localhost alone (without :3000) it shows the basic 'it works'
But If I do my request with curl it succeded, why not on my node app